# IndexOutOfBoundException on filtering SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, filter, indexoutofboundsexception, simpleadapter

I sub classed `SimpleAdapter` to add some extra functionality to it, like changing background color, custom views and filtering. The background thing is working out great but the filter isn't. If I use the `SimpleFilter` provided by the adapter there is no problem at all, so I copied the methods from the source and put them into my adapter. Although I didn't touch anything I'll get a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when typing in the search term. Usually on the second or third character.

I copied the whole class but the interesting part is the `CustomFilter` `bindView` and `getView` is working great. After implementing the filter changed it stops working. The exception is caused by data.get(position) in the `bindView` method on the first line but the problem has to be the filter.

```
public class ChangingColorAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    int resource;
    int[] to;

    List<Map<String, String>> data, mUnfilteredData;
    String[] from;

    Context context;
    Resources res;
    Filter filter;

    /*
     * A custom adapter which changes background colors on the elements
     * and implements custom filtering
     */
    public ChangingColorAdapter(Context context,
            List<Map<String, String>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {

        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.data = data;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.res = context.getResources();

    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if(filter != null) return filter;
        else return filter = new CustomFilter();
    }

    /*
     * A custom filter which is copied from the simplefilter in simpleadapter.
     * Changed word check from .startswith to .contains
     */
    private class CustomFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (mUnfilteredData == null) {
                mUnfilteredData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>(data);
            }

            if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
                List<Map<String, String>> list = mUnfilteredData;
                results.values = list;
                results.count = list.size();
            } else {
                String prefixString = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();

                List<Map<String, String>> unfilteredValues = mUnfilteredData;
                int count = unfilteredValues.size();

                ArrayList<Map<String, ?>> newValues = new ArrayList<Map<String, ?>>(count);

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    Map<String, ?> h = unfilteredValues.get(i);
                    if (h != null) {

                        int len = to.length;

                        for (int j=0; j<len; j++) {
                            String str =  (String)h.get(from[j]);

                            String[] words = str.split(" ");
                            int wordCount = words.length;

                            for (int k = 0; k < wordCount; k++) {
                                String word = words[k];

                                if (word.toLowerCase().contains(prefixString)) {
                                    newValues.add(h);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                results.values = newValues;
                results.count = newValues.size();
            }

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            data = (List<Map<String, String>>) results.values;
            if (results.count > 0) {
                 notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                 notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        } else {
            v = convertView;
        }

        bindView(position, v);

        if(position%2!=0) {
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        }
        else {
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        }

        return v;
    }

    /*
     * Iterate over all elements, check which type the given view is and fill in the data
     */
    private void bindView(int position, View view) {
        final Map<String, String> dataSet = data.get(position);
        if (dataSet == null) {
            return;
        }

        final ViewBinder binder = getViewBinder();
        final String[] from = this.from;
        final int[] to = this.to;
        final int count = to.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View v = view.findViewById(to[i]);
            if (v != null) {
                final Object data = dataSet.get(from[i]);
                String text = data == null ? "" : data.toString();
                if (text == null) {
                    text = "";
                }

                boolean bound = false;
                if (binder != null) {
                    bound = binder.setViewValue(v, data, text);
                }

                if (!bound) {
                    if (v instanceof Checkable) {
                        if (data instanceof Boolean) {
                            ((Checkable) v).setChecked((Boolean) data);
                        } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
                            setViewText((TextView) v, text);
                        } else {
                            throw new IllegalStateException(v.getClass().getName() +
                                    " should be bound to a Boolean, not a " +
                                    (data == null ? "<unknown type>" : data.getClass()));
                        }
                    } else if (v instanceof TermView) {
                        if(text.length()==10) {
                            int year = Integer.parseInt(text.substring(0,4));
                            if(text.substring(5, 7).equals("04")) {
                                setViewText((TextView) v, res.getString(R.string.summerterm) + " " + year);
                            }
                            else {
                                setViewText((TextView) v, res.getString(R.string.winterterm) + " " + year + "/" + (year+1));
                            }   
                        }
                        else {
                            setViewText((TextView) v, text);
                        }
                    } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
                        setViewText((TextView) v, text);
                    } else if (v instanceof ImageView) {
                        if (data instanceof Integer) {
                            setViewImage((ImageView) v, (Integer) data);                            
                        } else {
                            setViewImage((ImageView) v, text);
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw new IllegalStateException(v.getClass().getName() + " is not a " +
                                " view that can be bounds by this SimpleAdapter");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
    data.clear();
    data.addAll((List<Map<String, String>>) results.values);
    if (results.count > 0) {
       notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
       notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No need to add `filter` and `bindView` methods, only make sure for `getView`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    if(position%2!=0) {
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    }
    else {
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    return v;
}
```