# How to filter a filtered ListView, using SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, listview, filter, simpleadapter

I've been working on this like all the day and I don't get any result!!

I've been searching the posts like 'multiple filters' and more stuff and nothing was OK.

I have a **SimpleAdapter** and a populated ListView. Now I'm making a custom search depending of the words. I'm separating the words from whitespaces. For example:

Immagine, my data is:

> Cat likes dog
>
> Dog likes mouse
>
> Mouse likes cheese
>
> Cat eats cheese

If I filter 'cat' I will have the next list:

> Cat likes dog
>
> Cat eats cheese

and if I filter again with 'cheese', I will get:

> Cat eats cheese

but instead, I AM GETTING THIS:

> Mouse likes cheese
>
> Cat eats cheese

So, I'm getting only the LAST FILTER.

This is my code:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {
String[] separated = (cs).split(" +"); 
// With conditions not metioned here, I'm supposed to enter only words and spaces like the examples
for (int i2 = 0; i2 < separated.length ; i2++)  {
    adapter3.getFilter().filter(separated[i2]);
    adapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();                            
    
}
```

}

Thanks in advance!!!

---

**EDIT:**

I got my CustomAdapter. I can see my results but I can't set my adapter, don't know why.
So, it doesn't show me when I `setAdapter(adapter)` that I created on another function.
This is my adapter:

```
    public class Adaptador extends SimpleAdapter implements Filterable {

    public Adaptador(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data,
            int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        filtrodoble fil = new filtrodoble();
        return fil;
    }
    
    public class filtrodoble extends Filter{

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FilterResults Result = new FilterResults();
            // if constraint is empty return the original names
            ArrayList<String> Filtered_Names = new ArrayList<String>();
            Filtered_Names = arraylista;
            if(constraint.length() == 0 ){
                Result.values = Filtered_Names;
                Result.count = Filtered_Names.size();
                return Result;
            }
            String nomestringa = String.valueOf(constraint);
            String[] separated = nomestringa.split(" +");

            for (int i=0;i<separated.length;i++){

            Filtered_Names = doSomethingVoid(Filtered_Names, String.valueOf(separated[i])); // it returns another ArrayList<string>
            }

            
            for (int i2 = 3; i2<Filtered_Names.size(); i2=i2+6)
            
            
            Result.values = Filtered_Names;
            Result.count = Filtered_Names.size();
            return Result;
            
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {

            try{
                arrayaux=null;
            arrayaux = (ArrayList<String>)results.values; // MY RESULTS ARE GREAT HERE
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return convertView;
      } 
}
```

**SOLVED!!**

I was having a lot ot lv.setAdapter(null) because of the parameters of OnTextChanged... some of then changed by missclick or whatever. Sorry!

;)

Comment: also tried with `getApplicationContext().this.adapter3.getFilter().filter(separated[i2]);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with the built in filter. You need to extend `SimpleAdapter` and write your own `Filter` class. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258115/indexoutofboundexception-on-filtering-simpleadapter) a post that will give you a hint on how  to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I still don't get it.

I'm a little bit begginer, so I'm sorry. I don't know how to create a custom filter... is there a good tutorial?? I've been visiting a lot and I don't understand anyone like my example.

Comment: First you need to understand how `ListView`, `Adapter` and `Filter` work. Google for the terms, read the Android doc and some tutorials. Google for "android listview custom adapter" or "android listview custom filter" etc. [This](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) is a nice tutorial about ListView and custom Adapter. And [here](http://software-workshop.eu/content/android-development-creating-custom-filter-listview) is one about custom Filters.

Comment: I did that, and I do know how ListView, Adapter and Filter works, but only with one `CharSequence`

Also I said before I don't find a good example for understanding how a `CustomAdapter` works.

Comment: What is wrong with the tutorial (the one from Lars Vogel) that i gave you the link to in the comment before? It shows very nice how to create a custom adapter. Once you have that custom adapter you add your own filter, as shown in the second tutorial.  You will only have ONE filter. In this filter you define yourself what you want to show and what not. You can filter for as many different strings as you like.

Comment: Hey, I got it, but now the adapter doesn't show with setAdapter... I'm going to EDIT my question.